# ImportError django is not found

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I installed *django* framework in virtual env and now it is given me an ***import error***.

> (WebEnvironment) D:\conda project\web\mysite>python manage.py runserver
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 8, in 
>   from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 14, in 
>       ) from exc
>   ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available o
>   n your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual env
>   ironment?

Comment: Are you using the virtual environment? You need to do something like this `my_env\Scripts\activate.bat` on windows. If you use some IDE, then you need to set your IDE to use that virtual environment.

Comment: Which version of django and python is installed on WebEnvironment ?

Comment: You need to install django from virtual environment. Can you check if it is installed in correct environment?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new virtual environment, you can follow the steps below.

```
    mkdir djangoproject
    
    cd djangoproject/
    
    pip install virtualenv
    
    virtualenv myvenv
```

Thus, you create a new virtual environment.

```
    pip freeze
    
    which python
    
    source myvenv/bin/activate
```

We activated the virtual environment.
(To deactivate -> myvenv deactivate)

```
    pip install django
    
    pip freeze
    
    django-admin startproject myproject
    
    cd myproject/
    
    python manage.py runserver
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the traceback you are getting,

I'd make sure that the virtual environment is activated, and also that the Django module was installed by running these command.

**1.** Activate the virtual environment in case it's not activated yet

```
$ source path-to-venv/bin/activate
```

**2.** See all the installed modules in the virtual environment and confirm the Django module exists.

```
$ pip freeze
```

**3.** In case Django is missing from the virtual environment's installed modules, then run this command to install it

```
$ pip install django==version#
```

or

```
$ pip install django   # to install the latest version
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because you're calling django with the system's python and not the one inside your virtualenv.

Activate your virtualenv and then type:

```
python -m pip install django
```

Remember to always call python inside your virtualenv. Let's say, like so (**on Windows**):

```
python .\manage.py runserver
```

That's it! Django will be recognized.